# qtranslate (language definition) when translation for selected language doesn't exist

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

I'm using qtranslate, and whenever selected language translation doesn't exists it outputs text like this: (English) This is english text. So it gives me (language) string inside the output. I'd like to get rid of this.

So that if I select russian language, and text is not translated yet I see english language text but no (English) attached automatically.

Any ideas how to do this? I looked in backend carefully and it doesn't seem to have any settings for this.

I'd do php trim or smth else but there should be easier way to do this...

Comment: Copy the english translation over other languages. That's how i cope with it.

Comment: @Zlatev I thought about this too, but this is such an ugly solution. I'd prefer to do something programatic.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's helpful, but I remember of setting a generic language `all` to deal with some empty content. That site is no more, and I'm not sure if I found this hint in qTrans forum or at WP.org.

Answer (score 1):

you should find this options in qtranslate configuration page: "hide not translated content" (or something similar to)

Comment: That's not helpful. Please provide more details and use Upper-/Lowercase letters. Thanks.

Comment: i can't understand what could change by using upper/lowercase letters. Anyway: if you choose that option (i do not know which is the correct label 'cause my wordpress setup is in italian by the way), qtranslate hide contents when they're not present in that specific language

Comment: A) Please update your question with additional info B) It's about _writing answers in proper Upper-/lowercase letters_. At least this is no chat.

Comment: This just removes posts from the loop. I have different requirements.